# Controlling what Web/MSDeploy publishes: PDF files?

Tags: asp.net, msdeploy

I'm using VS2010 and WebDeploy(MSDeploy) to automate publishing an ASP.NET web-site to the public server. The problem is it doesn't publish .PDF files. They seem to be ignored, maybe as a build artifact, or non-publishable content. How can I change the list of file extensions or folders that are included in the deploy?

Answer (score 7):

I assume the PDF files are included in Visual Studio. Right-click the file in Solution Explorer -> click Properties. Set Build Action to "Content".  Then Web Deploy will pick it up.